# how to get thumbnail images on list.phtml page in magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: image, thumbnails, magento-1.9

how to show thumbnail images from **view.phtml** page on **list.phtml** page in magento 1.9.2.4, I have tried lot of things but nothing really works for me, kindly share something that can solve my problem. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php //get images for product
              $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
              $helper = Mage::Helper('catalog/image');
              foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
                  echo "<img src='" . $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $image->getFile())->resize(80) . "' />";
              }
              ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item->getProduct(), 'thumbnail');
```

Comment: how to add this kindly share details